# Detected a breaking change due to missing at least one parameter

Tags: sdk, cloud, upgrade, sap-cloud-sdk

While trying to generate java source files from edmx files, I am getting this error:

> Found entity type A_MaterialStockType from set A_MaterialStock Detected a breaking change due to missing at least one parameter

Below is the plugin config:

[image]

Previously I was generating using 4.28.0 with that generation was fine.
Currently upgrading to SAP Cloud SDK 5.1.0

Anyone faced this issue? Any solution ?

Project java version is 17.

Thanks.

I am following the steps mentioned in [this guide](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/5.0-upgrade-steps) and the links within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue most likely relates to a "backwards-compatibility-check" that is part of the generator.

Here the generator tries to produce an order for the parameter to stay compatible to previous VDM generated by it.
In your case it seems that this seems to fail due to a missing/new parameter of some method. This happens quite often with new updates taken from the SAP Business Accelerator Hub

To workaround that issue you can delete the previously generated code and generated it fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Schubert, I had deleteOutputDirectory as true in the plugin config.
So I thought it will clean up.

But when I deleted manually the output vdm folder, it generated the classes without issue.

Thanks.